# Ideas for a limit calculation

Tags: integration, limits, absolute-value

The limit to show is the following:
$$
\lim_{t\to \infty} \int_\mathbb{R}\left|\frac{-\sin x \sin tx}{x^2} \right|dx
$$

- A direct splitting of the integral into $\int_{-\infty}^0+\int_0^{+\infty}$ in order to get rid of the absolute values does not seem to be possible, since the denominator is always positive and the sin products behave as shown below: (plotted in WolframAlpha)

[image]

- How can one proceed in such circumstances? Are there known identities that help simplify this limit computation?

Comment: Why do you keep the minus sign inside the absolute value?

Comment: @uniquesolution I don't see how that can make a difference, since the sin product is fluctuating around 0 anyway (constantly changing sign).

Comment: It does not make a difference, not because the sin product is fluctuating, but because $|z|=|-z|$ for every $z$. So it is a little unsusual to leave it inside, although perfectly correct.

Comment: @uniquesolution alright, indeed

Comment: Did you check whether the integral converges for any value of $t$ different from zero? If it does not converge, the limit is of course undefined.

Comment: Just to be sure, what do you exactly intend to prove with this limit? the integral's convergece?

Comment: i would guess that the integral is stronly dominated from the region where $x\approx 0 $ because of the heavy oscillations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your integral $I(t)$ is such that (as the function under the integral sign is $\geq0$)
$$I(t)\geq F(t)=\int_0^1\frac{|\sin(x)||\sin(tx)|}{x^2}dx$$

Now, if $x\in [0,1]$, we get (by the MVT) that $\sin(x)=x\cos(c)$ for some $c\in ]0,x[$, hence $\sin(x)\geq mx$ with $m=\cos(1)$.

Hence
$$F(t)\geq m\int_0^1\frac{|\sin(tx)|}{x}dx$$
Change of variable $tx=u$ in the last integral gives:

$$F(t)\geq m\int_0^t\frac{|\sin(u)|}{u}du$$

As $\displaystyle \int_0^{+\infty}\frac{|\sin(u)|}{u}du=+\infty$, we get that $I(t)\to +\infty$ if $t \to +\infty$.

Comment: Very neat! Could you add a brief explanation for the first and second inequalities you wrote?(as in why we expect the first one to hold, and how the second was obtained) Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the edit. One last question, at the end we're dealing with a variant of the sine integral, now I know that $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}dx = \frac{\pi}{2},$ but with the inclusion of the absolute values, how did you conclude that the sine integral goes to infinity here?

Comment: With $I_k=\int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi}\frac{|\sin(t)|}{t}dt$, you have this integral $=\sum_{k\geq 0} I_k$. Now by the change of variable $t=k\pi+x$, you get $I_k=\int_0^{\pi}\frac{|\sin(x)|}{k\pi+x}dx\geq \int_0^{\pi}\frac{|\sin(x)|}{\pi+k\pi}dx=\frac{c}{k+1}$ for a constant $c>0$. Hence $\sum I_k=+\infty$.